# Is it possible to change the theme of multimedia icons on the panel в xfce4-mpc-plugin?

Tags: xfce, plugins, icon-themes

**In my xfce4 panel, gray and dark icons are almost invisible.**

Do you know Is it possible to change the theme of multimedia icons on the panel in xfce4-mpc-plugin? How to make the icons back, stop, pause and forward displayed with light icons.

*Thank you for help! Best regards, Sergey!*